# Two favorites combined: A Crypto Sudoku

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, rebus, sudoku, crossword-clues

Below is just a plain old sudoku. However, the clues given are a little bit different than usual. It's your job to use them properly. *Note:* Not every letter makes the same digit, nor every digit is created by the same letters.

The final answer is in the circled numbers, which is nice if you get it :)

[image: sudoku]

### Here are the clues you need to solve the sudoku:

#### Across:

1. Pseudocereal
2. Massive effect of the union in a succesful claim at last.
3. Human system with mythical powers.
4. Scold up your doorway!
5. Tool of both a data scientist and a carpenter.

#### Down:

1. Never capture what you can't control.
2. 

[image: photo]

3. Joker
4. 

[image: picture]

5. It's indignity to jab it once.
6. 

[image: rebus]

---

***Good luck!***

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The final answer is:

> **BADGE**

How are numbers assigned to letters?

> That's the wrong question. One should rather ask: How can stretches of nine digits be mapped to nine-letter words. The answers to the clues (which don't have to be single words) are made up of nine unique letters. *Any* nine letters.
>
>  Sort the letters of each entry. The position of each letter in the sorted letters is the value for that letter. For example, let's look at the first entry, **BUCKWHEAT**. Its alphabetically sorted letters **ABCEHKTUW** map to 123456789, so **BUCKWHEAT** is 283695417.
>
>  (Strictly speaking, the down clues could have duplicate letters because they are not lined up in a column, so that "aardvarks" could map to 126493758 or 327491658 or any other permutations of the a's (123) and r's (67), but I've assumed that they must be unique, too.)

What are the answers to the clues:

> **Across**
>  Pseudocereal
>  **BUCKWHEAT**
>
>  Massive effect of the union in a succesful claim at last.
>  **IMPACTFUL** — massive, PACT (union) in (cla)IM + success(FUL)
>  (Found by fljx. I kinda see it, but I'm not convinced.)
>
>  Human system with mythical powers.
>  **LYMPHATIC** — anagram of MYTHICAL + P (= power)
>
>  Scold up your doorway!
>  **OBJURGATE** — to scold, sounds like "up your gate"
>
>  Tool of both a data scientist and a carpenter.
>  **WORKBENCH** — name for a worktop and a program suite
>
>
>  **Down**
>  Never capture what you can't control.
>  **BLACKFISH** — tagline for the Netflix documentary of the same name
>  (Also found by fljx. I don't watch series. I waste my time on PSE.)
>
>  (image of a railway control tower)
>  **SIGNAL BOX**
>
>  Joker
>  **HARLEQUIN**
>
>  (image of groups of six chromosomes)
>  **HEXAPLOID**
>
>  It's indignity to jab it once.
>  **ABJECTION** — anagram of JAB IT ONCE
>
>  (image of snake & hare)
>  **QUICKSAND** — a rebus: the QUICK rabbit before S + AND

What does the grid look like:

> [image: the filled-in sudoku grid]

What's the overall answer?

> The numbered cells give **21475**. That can't be a letter ordering, because 7 is out of range. But if we use the numbers as positions of the letters in the alphabet, A1Z26 in PSE parlance, we get **BADGE**.

Comment: A couple of clue explanations, rot13("Arire pncgher jung lbh pna'g pbageby" vf gur fhogvgyr bs n argsyvk qbphzragnel. Naq vzcnpgshy vf (-pyn)VZ + CNPG + (-fhpprff)SHY.)

Comment: Very good, both M Oehm and fljx. I see I have made a small mistake about the final answer, I have edited the puzzle. I had put accidentally the 5th one in the wrong square. You don't need to search through 45000 words, there is an easy way to find the final answer.

Comment: Oh, I see. A case of Bad Grid Enumeration ... `;)`

Comment: Very well done! Let's hope this answer will give you a 21475 ;)